# Expo standalone FCM push notifications are not rececived by android device after switch online

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, expo

When i try to send notification when target device internet connection is off and next turn on internet connection i receive no notification.

There is no problem with notifications when device is online.

This is standalone Expo aplication with [FCM notifications](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v30.0.0/guides/using-fcm).

Based on [FCM docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#ttl) it should work.

> ...When this happens, FCM stores the message and delivers it as soon as it's feasible

Tested on two different devices, same result. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Can't believe. This is just default [expo](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/push-notifications) ttl settings.

> ...Time to Live: the number of seconds for which the message may be kept
>   around for redelivery if it hasn't been delivered yet. Defaults to 0.